# AppCenter shows fewer apps in secondary administrator session. How to synchronize sources?

Tags: appcenter, software-sources

I am on Elementary OS 7.1 and I have two administrator users.

In session 1, the AppCenter gives me a wide choice of applications.
In session 2, for a more recently created admin user, the AppCenter gives me little choice.

How can I have as many choices of software installations in both sessions ?
I was thinking both sessions would use the same **/etc/apt/sources*** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I somehow found the reason of the discrepancy between the 2 appcenter when reading a little phrase on https://flatpak.org/setup/elementary%20OS

> Note: After installing one app from a remote like Flathub, all other
> apps from that remote will also automatically show up in AppCenter.

So I did install some flatpack using a link to some flatpakref file and then Voila ! all bunch of sotware available in the user 2 AppCenter :)